# "super advanced" excel, EXPERT NEEDED

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, lookup

[image: Please Take a look at image below]

I am trying to write a formula for cell J8 that returns the money value by looking up all the rest of information in column J. For clarity, I want a formula in J8 that takes the 3 values above it to find the $$$ in column H by reference. So J6 = 1000 leading to the top section, J4 = A leading to the first 3 rows, J5 = Average leading to H8 which is $50

I have been able to get close using if multiple times, but I would like it to run smoothly, as in my actual template there are close to 100 charts instead of just these 2, so the If statement formulas would be never ending.

I believe the formula will need multiple index match functions or Lookup match functions, but I have been unable to help.

If someone could provide a formula for me, I'd Appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: An IF formula is likely the easiest. Otherwise you could name each cell that has a specific value (create custom named range) and then you can simply refer to that cell by name.

Comment: it's unclear what you want to achieve, please share desired results, and also please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: Its not that unclear to me. He wants a formula in J7 that takes the 3 values above it to find the $$$ in column H by reference. So J6 = 1000 leading to the top section, J4 = A leading to the first 3 rows, J5 = Average leading to H8 which is $50.

Comment: Lookup the function =INDIRECT. It may help you shorten the IF statement quite a bit.

Comment: If you have the most recent version of Excel, you could use the IFS function. It's a lot easier than nesting a bunch of IF statements.

Comment: Create a helper table where you concatenate the three criteria from the table in one column and put the associated value in the next column.  Then do a lookup using a concatenation of the lookup values.

Answer (score 1):

Both vlookup and index/match requires a different type of data structure. Offset is the formula that closes matches to the structure you are using. 
Step 1, find the starting cell. In the example you have made, this is $c$4
Step 2, figure out how many rows and how many columns you need to move from the start cell to the answer. The column is easy as it is always a 5.

to find the number of rows will take equations.
For the 1000 or 2000, 1000=0, 2000=15. This can be done with algebra or an if(j6=1000,0,ifj6=2000,15,"Whatever error message for missing or wrong selection")

Similarly, For the A, B, if(J4="A",2,if(J4="B",8,"Error message"))
For the average, if(J5="Good",1,if(J5="Average",2,if(J5="Fair",3)))

combining everything is

- =OFFSET($C$4,IF(J6=1000,0,IF(J6=2000,17,"Error"))+IF(J5="Average",2,IF(J5="good",1,IF(J5="fair",3,"Error")))+IF(J4="A",2,IF(J6=B,8,"Error")),5)

I am not sure how your diagram matches to underlying cells, so this may need to be tweaked a little

Comment: Thank you for this! This appears to do what I need, just 2 questions to accompany your formula.  Notice, There is an Excellent row in the second table and later on a "poor" would I just need to add from the +(IFJ5="Excellent",1,IF(J5="good",2,IF(J5="Average",3,IF(J5="fair",4,IF(J5="poor",5,"Error"))))) and the second question is where does that 17 come from, as I will have to write multiple of the equations? Thanks again

Comment: the 17 was eyeballing how far it was from the the cell with "1000"  to the cells with "2000" in it.  It might be 15 or some other number. The targets appear to be larger than a single cell.  It will take some tweaking to get it right since will be translating big to a specific cell.  For poor or other words, just figure out the math and adjust.  Start gives you a relative 0 or if Row=column=0, you end up with $c$4, Major is the 1000/2000, then Group is A/B, then exact is Good,etc.  for each section add appropriate rows.